# How to do simple natural language categorization

Tags: natural-language-processing

How would you go about parsing a sentence like
"Bought two kilos of steak from Acme supermarket" into a data structure like the following JSON representation:

```
{
  item: {name: "steak", tags: "meat,beef" },
  quantity: { value: 2, unit: "kg"},
  source: "ACME Supermarket"
}
```

?

I'm looking for a high-level conceptual overview of where to start e.g. some papers or introductory material that don't require PhD level knowledge. For context, this is part of the preliminary investigation for a personal expense tracker I'm planning to build.

To break it down a little further, I'm interested in basic named entity recognition, and categorization strategies. I don't have a CS education, so you may want to keep that in mind when answering :) Thanks in advance. Not interested in 3rd party web services, since this is a learning exercise, and is intended to work offline.

Comment: I'm sure you're aware but natural language processing is no simple task. [Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo).

Comment: Ha! Yes I am, and painfully so. I think I've seen that before, possibly from http://nlpwp.org or the early material from pre-Coursera http://nlp-class.org. I am, however, hoping the reduced problem space makes for "simpler", if not necessarily "simple", approaches.

Comment: PhD level knowledge doesn't include how to do this. It's an extraordinarily complicated question...Imagine the amount of work that would go into categorizing a simple list of things that can be *bought*. Now, imagine a category list of places that *sell*. Now build all the natural language causal links between the two. Now add another person.

Comment: What I'm hoping for is something just slightly more sophisticated than looking for synonyms of "bought" and determining the object of the verb. I worked on a retail ordering system that accepted that sort of input, but it was pretty much a spelling corrector coupled with a dictionary that failed if it couldn't find a reasonable match. The solution needn't be probablistic. I realize my optimism is likely based on extreme naivete, but surely, there's got to be somewhere to start? :(

Comment: If the problem space is sufficiently simplified, you're looking at nothing more than a Domain-Specific Language (DSL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to **define your own syntax which *appears* to be natural (or close-to-natural) language, even though it's actually much more rigid.**

For example, a SQL select statement:  `SELECT <something> AS <foo> FROM <table> WHERE <something else> IS <a value>` (note that I replaced `=` with `IS` to make the point, but that the capitalization is *not* important).

In your case, it would be `BOUGHT <quantity> OF <thing> FROM <location>`.  Then you just have to parse `<quantity>`, `<thing>`, and `<location>` to match them up against known items.

```
switch (quantityString)
{
   case "a": 
   case "1": 
   case "a single": 
   case "one":
     return 1;
   case "a pair":
   case "2":
   case "two":
     return 2;
   ....
 }
```

You could even make the first word variable input too, but only from a select set of known verbs (the way SQL has `SELECT`, `DELETE`, `INSERT`, etc).  You could handle derivatives of them ("purchased" vs "bought") similarly.

This would be an example of defining a [Domain-Specific Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) like @Robert-Harvey mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, I just might go with this approach. Can't upvote you until I hit 15 though, sorry :( I was hoping for something between this and Siri, but it increasingly looks like there's no middle ground. Might go with a thesaurus to make it a little more "intelligent".

Comment: @OkalOtieno - Yeah, a thesaurus could certainly work, if you can implement it to have reasonably quick lookups.  Just be aware that tenses can really mess it up.  `Buy -> Bought` vs `Purchase -> Purchased`.

Comment: The trick is to have people who don't know how your program works provide test phrases.

Comment: Sounds like a great idea. I'll get my co-workers to give me sample inputs. Thank you :)

Comment: @OkalOtieno - Sounds like a good way to do it.  Good luck!  And welcome to Stack Exchange!

Comment: @Bobson Thanks for taking time to respond :) I'm still holding out hope for different suggestions. Shall accept it once it's clear that this is the best strategy, which seems to be the case at the moment.